# Campos NULL usando PIVOT a en tabla PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-12c

Solicito de su colaboración debido a que me encuentro realizando un `pivot` a una tabla y me esta separando los registros por campos `null`, aun asi deje los campos en 0 con `NVL`

```
producto  | valor
----- ----+-------
Camisas   | 1200
Gorras    | 0
Medias    | 0
Gafas     | 100
Zapatos   | 0
```

Código pivot

```
select * from productos
 PIVOT (sum(valor)
   for titulos in ('producto', 'valor')) AS pivot_producto
```

Resultado:

```
 producto |  Camisas  | Gorras |    Medias   | Gafas | Zapatos
 ---------+-----------+--------+-------------+-------+----------
   valor  |    NULL   |  NULL  |    NULL     |  100  |   NULL
   valor  |    1200   |  NULL  |    NULL     |  NULL |   NULL
```

Resultado esperado:

```
 producto |  Camisas  | Gorras |    Medias   | Gafas | Zapatos
 ---------+-----------+--------+-------------+-------+----------
   valor  |    1200   |  NULL  |    NULL     |  100  |   NULL
```

Opcional

```
 producto |  Camisas  | Gorras |    Medias   | Gafas | Zapatos
 ---------+-----------+--------+-------------+-------+----------
   valor  |    1200   |    0   |      0      |  100  |    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comparto el query para obtener el resultado opcional:

```
DECLARE @columnas VARCHAR(max)
SET @columnas = ''
SELECT @columnas =  coalesce(@columnas + '[' + cast(producto as varchar(12)) + '],', '')
FROM (select distinct producto from productos) as DTM
set @columnas = left(@columnas,LEN(@columnas)-1)

DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);

set @SQLString = N'
  SELECT * FROM #productos
PIVOT
(
sum(valor)
   FOR producto 
   IN (' + @columnas + ')
) AS pivot_producto;'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
```

Comment: existe la posibilidad de que las columnas sean dinámicas en el IN y no manuales..?

Comment: Ya modifique el comentario, espero te ayude.

Answer (score 1):

Las otras columnas en tu tabla generan los "huecos", selecciona en un subquery únicamente las columnas que necesitas:

```
SELECT nvl(producto,0) producto
     , camisas
     , gorras 
  FROM (SELECT producto, valor FROM productos)
  PIVOT (sum(valor)
         FOR producto in ( 'Producto' producto
                         , 'Camisas' camisas
                         , 'Gorras' gorras
                         )
        )
```